# How to put image URL in openpyxl - Django

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I have read the docs to [Load an image](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html?highlight=image#inserting-an-image), but when I try that, I have a FileNotFoundError. In my Django webapp all the images work on DEBUG and also on Deploy, I have configured Apache to serve them, so there's no problem with that.

These are the URL's that I have tried:

```
img = Image('../../archivos/blusapolo.jpg')
img = Image('blusapolo.jpg')
img = Image(settings.MEDIA_URL+'blusapolo.jpg')
img = Image('http://127.0.0.1:8000/archivos/blusapolo.jpg')
```

The last one was just a try, I know that I need a "relative" path, or however it is called.

### My question is, it's possible to save an image to a xlsx file with openpyxl using DJango? How?

Here is my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/excel/?numero=57

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'myapp',
 'django_tables2')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/developer/mysystem/systemvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/developer/mysystem/systemvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/developer/mysystem/systemvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/developer/mysystem/myapp/viewCotizacion.py" in get
  135.         img = Image('/archivos/blusapolo.jpg')#,size=(75,100)
File "/home/developer/mysystem/systemvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py" in __init__
  49.         self.image = _import_image(img)
File "/home/developer/mysystem/systemvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/drawing/image.py" in _import_image
  36.         img = PILImage.open(img)
File "/home/developer/mysystem/systemvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py" in open
  2280.         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /cotizaciones/
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/archivos/blusapolo.jpg'
```

Comment: can you paste the exact traceback you get.

Comment: @NabeelAhmed I edited my question, you can see it there

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear: either the image is not where you think it is; the Django process does not have the relevant permissions to access it.

Comment: @CharlieClark and why this only happens with openpyxl? If you read my question, I use images in other parts of my web app and everything works fine, I know how to access to them and Django has permissions, I have used all that URL variations and with all of them had the same error, and I repeat, this only happens with openpyxl.

Comment: Can't help you with the Django part, sorry.

Comment: @CharlieClark Ok, no problem :D